# How to retrieve the values for the particular key from CFMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

In C++ `EventType.find(1)->second` can be used to find the value for the key 1.

I am new to Objective C.I have implemented `CFDictionary` to addvalue onto it.But how do i

`retreive` and view the `values` of the particular key.

### EDITED:

```
CFNumberRef tId = CFNumberCreate(NULL,kCFNumberShortType,&st);
CFDictionarySetValue(cfdict,tId,st);
NSLog(@"The value is:%s",(CFDictionaryGetValue(cfdict,tId)));
```

Its running without error but i could not get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `CFMutableDictionary` says:

> The basic interface for managing dictionaries is provided by `CFDictionary` Reference.

... which leads you to [`CFDictionaryGetValue()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001195-CH1g-F11040).

Answer (score 0):

Please do not edit your posts to ask another unrelated question.

Anyway: You are using the wrong format specifier: `%s` is used to print C strings. You can use Objective-C's `%@` format specifier to print the object's description.

If you want to use pure Core Foundation you can use `CFShow(object)`;