# How to do look ups on the CFDictionary

Tags: c++, objective-c, porting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve the values for the particular key from CFMutableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006545/how-to-retrieve-the-values-for-the-particular-key-from-cfmutabledictionary)

In C++:

```
typedef struct
{
     unsigned short wId;
     bool bPersists;
     unsigned short uPeriod;
     bool bStop;
}stTimer;

unsigned short wId;
stTimer pEvent;
CTypedPtrMap<CMapWordToPtr,WORD,stTimer*>m_cIdMap;
if(m_cIdMap.Lookup(wId,pEvent))
{
    //find and remove the event pEvent;
}
```

I need to port the same functionality to Objective-C

I could be able to set and get the values into the `CFDictionary`, but I need to do look ups into the dictionary with the `wId`(key) and the `pEvent`(value).

Comment: How many times are you going to ask how get a value out of CFDictionary? [How to retrieve the values for the particular key from CFMutableDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006545/) [Could not remove value from a CFMutableDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014056/) [CFDictionaryGetValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007575/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an NSDictionary and box the keys with NSNumber (assuming you have created a class to represent your stTimer struct.

```
[myDictionary setObject: myStTimer forKey: [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: [myStTimer wId]]];

StTimer* mySTTimer = [myDictionary objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: anId]];
```

I don't see any point of going for a lower level interface.  You might as well stick with the C++ version.